# MonoDevelop 3.0.6 Doesn't run

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have unity4 installed on my system.MonoDevelop is bundled with it. I installed MonoDevelop3.0.6. Now when I click the icon to start it it won't run, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The bundled MonoDevelop application is a custom version built specifically for Unity, so you can't just replace it with a later MonoDevelop version and expect it to work. Several users have released guides for using later MonoDevelop versions, e.g. 3 or 4, with Unity, some links for further reading:

http://www.cliffordroche.ca/monodevelop-4-xamarin-studio-debugging-in-unity/
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/171632-MonoDevelop-4-aka-Xamarin-Studio

As per the last link, if you're coding in C# it seems like you can use MonoDevelop 4 (and maybe 3) by doing this:

> On the OS X, I renamed the monodevelop that came with Unity, then put Xamarin Studio into the Unity folder and renamed it MonoDevelop.app. It works perfectly (for C# development that is). It even opens files on the correct line # etc. For Debugging or Unity-Javascript, you need to stick with Unity-Monodevelop.

[Permalink](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/171632-MonoDevelop-4-aka-Xamarin-Studio?p=1175100&viewfull=1#post1175100)

The next Unity releae, 4.3, will bundle MonoDevelop 4.